# Como adicionar duas legendas utilizando geom_sf e geom_raster no ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu tenho estes [dados](https://easyupload.io/8q9lnv):

```
structure(list(lon = c(-84.375, -84.125, -83.875, -83.625, -83.375, 
-83.125, -82.875, -82.625, -82.375, -82.125, -81.875, -81.625, 
-81.375, -81.125, -80.875, -80.625, -80.375, -80.125, -79.875, 
-79.625, -79.375, -79.125, -78.875, -78.625, -78.375, -78.125, 
-77.875, -77.625, -77.375, -77.125), lat = c(-52.625, -52.625, 
-52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, 
-52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, 
-52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, 
-52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625, -52.625
), pr = c(743.868774414062, 745.477661132812, 740.24267578125, 
737.242797851562, 734.242919921875, 731.242980957031, 800.98876953125, 
803.612670898438, 806.236572265625, 808.860473632812, 712.187622070312, 
710.083129882812, 710.976013183594, 712.867919921875, 919.867614746094, 
918.26416015625, 916.660705566406, 915.677490234375, 945.941589355469, 
946.579406738281, 947.217224121094, 947.855041503906, 1108.41198730469, 
1108.90100097656, 1112.51672363281, 1116.13244628906, 1070.11169433594, 
1069.80126953125, 1069.49096679688, 1074.63659667969)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Estou utilizando o código abaixo, entretanto a legenda para o shape dos países e da bacia não aparece se deixar a legenda para o arquivo raster. Segue o código:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("RColorBrewer")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot() +
geom_raster(data = datapr, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = pr)) +
scale_fill_gradientn("kg m-2 s-1", colours = rev(brewer.pal(10, "RdBu"))) +
geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(world), aes(fill = "Países"),show.legend = "polygon",
          colour = "red", alpha = 0) +
geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(sfshape),aes(fill = "Bacia"),
          colour = "blue",alpha = 0, show.legend = "polygon")
```

Gostaria de saber como ajustar o código, especificamente na função geom_sf para aparecer sua legenda, seja polígono, linha ou ponto e manter a legenda do geom_raster.

Comment: Faltou como reproduzirmos os outros dados além de `world`

Comment: @TomásBarcellos os dados estão num link na pergunta num arquivo .RData

Comment: Essa não é a "boa prática" aqui no SOpt. Inclui o resultado de `dput(head(minha_base, 30))` para cada um dos dados que são usados na pergunta (exceto os que vem de pacote com o o `world`)

Comment: Outra coisa, a resposta não resolve? Mesmo com a limitação dos dados?

Comment: @TomásBarcellos não resolve. Veja que além de colocar a legenda para o geom_sf, preciso dela para os dois arquivos world e sfshape (não conseguir gerar o dput do último), ainda preciso de uma legenda para o geom_raster (coloquei agora pergunta)

Answer (score 1):

### Breve explicação sobre estéticas no `ggplot2`

O `ggplot` enxerga as estéticas sob dois pontos de vista possíveis. No primeiro deles uma estética - digamos uma cor - inclui informação (caso em que ela está dentro do `aes()`); no segundo ele não informa nada e é apenas uma atributo estético do gráfico (caso em que ele está fora do `aes()` e é atribuído como argumento da chamada da camada.

Exemplo do primeiro caso:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(cyl)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do segundo caso:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(col = "blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que vale ressaltar aqui é que nos segundo caso, como a cor não adiciona informação ao gráfico, ela não precisa de uma legenda. Afinal, ela não precisa ser "decodificada" pelo leitor do gráfico.´

Ou seja, para corrigir o seu mapa você deve corrigir a chamada do `ggplot`para que o aspecto destacado fique dentro do `aes()`.

### Refazendo o mapa

Sem os dados compartilhados crio um exemplo similar que poderás usar para adaptar o seu código.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sf)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

world %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(destaque = ifelse(name == "Brazil", "Destaque", "Sem destaque")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = destaque)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Destaque" = "darkgreen", "Sem destaque" = "transparent"))
```

O que é feito aqui é incluir uma variável que será usada para definir que região do mapa "destacar" e incluir ela como `fill` dentro do `aes()`. Depois, apenas por questões estéticas, as cores para os casos foram ajustadas no `scale_fill_manual` com seus respectivos par de valores e cores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Alternativa para muitas camadas

Caso não seja possível trabalhar com um único objeto `sf` e você precise de múltiplas camadas, como seu problema acima parece sugerir, uma opção é proceder uma transformação similar apenas nos dados que quer destacar. **É importante notar que é necessário mapear uma estética a uma variável para gerar a legenda**. Segue exemplo:

```
# Dado que será destacado
brasil <- ne_countries(country = "brazil", returnclass = "sf") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(destaque = ifelse(name == "Brazil", "Destaque", "Sem destaque")) 

world %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = destaque), data = brasil) + # incluido em segunda camada
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Destaque" = "darkgreen", "Sem destaque" = "transparent"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]